# Convergence of sequence of inner product with orthogonal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose X is a Seperable Hilbert space and E={$u_{n}$ : $n\in $N} is denumerable orthonormal basis.Let ($x_{n}$) be a sequence in X and $x\in X$.Show that if $\langle x_{n}$,$u_{m} \rangle$ converges to $\langle x$,$u_{m} \rangle$ for all $m\in N $ , then $\langle x_{n},y \rangle$ converges to $\langle x$,$y \rangle$ for all $y\in X$

My attempt:
$\langle x_{n}-x$,$y \rangle$ = $\lim_{m\to\infty}\langle S_{m}$,$y \rangle$ where $S_{m}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\langle x_{n}-x$,$u_{i} \rangle u_{i}  $
Now, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_{n}-x$,$y \rangle  = \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty} \langle S_{m}$,$y \rangle $
If limits above can be exchanged  , since  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle S_{m}$,$y \rangle= 0 $ ,we can conclude the proof. Im not sure if this is correct or when the limits can be exchanged.Does the seperability condition comes in play anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct. Let $E=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $u_m(k)=\delta_{m,k}$. The sequence given by $x_n(k)=n\delta_{n,k}$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n,u_m\rangle=0$ for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$, but if we take $y(k)=\frac 1 k$, then
$$
\langle x_n,y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty n\delta_{n,k}\frac 1k=1.
$$